Review this TTL to RS485 Adapter (SP3485)
I am trying to make a TTL-to-RS485 adapter between an ESP32-C6 and a USB-ACM-TTL-serial chip using a SP3485 driver (because it is in stock at the PCB manufacturer).
This uses an existing design, so I would like to avoid using a microcontroller's GPIO to switch between TX/RX, and so we came up with the circuit below to receive unless it is transmitting.
Most of what I will be doing is console access to a terminal command line on a remote device (with the same circuit on its side); the remote device will spew data once per second; the UART is at 115200, but this can be changed if necessary.
It would be nice if I can flash the device as well... but I do not know if the half-duplex nature of RS485 will work with idf.py flash.

Another RS485 datasheet shows typical usage for this chip as follows:

Questions:

What is Rt and how do I terminate each end of the bus?
Is my transmit detection implemented properly?
Will this work with idf.py flash?
Other considerations or problems to consider?


See also: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/718720/ttl-to-rs485-converter-problems


Rt is a termination resistor. You terminate an RS-485 bus by putting one Rt at each end of the bus just like in the picture. The resistor should match the characteristic impedance of the cable, so in a typical RS-485 system it will be 120 ohms.

Unlikely correct, if you want real RS-485. You are only transmitting when ESP wants to send a logic zero level. This essentially makes it a wired-OR similar to a open-drain bus, like what CAN bus is. It may work but all bets are guesswork. The transistor will always turn off a bit late and make the logic low level shorter from the beginning. The transistor should turn on rather quickly but the chip will still send a short rising edge before it stops driving the bus to logic high level. If you want the open drain or CANbus alike mode, you might be better off driving the enable pin directly with the data, not the data pin. Or some modules implement a circuit which keeps the transmit enabled for a delay until no data is transmitted. Which needs a protocol that takes turns so there is a small defined gap to allow for bua turnaround.

Unlikely that it will work. Also the idf.py isn't the one communicating, it calls esptool.py to do the work. The computer would need to have a RS-485 port. Or need to do a conversion from RS-232 port to RS-485 port. Generally on computers the RTS output is uses for transmitter enable. The eaptool cannot know that, and it can't use RS-485 handshake mode as it does not expect it needs to control it. Of course if you use one of those autotransmitting devices or use your open-drain CAN-alike bus, the program does not need to know it. The next problem is that you only extended the data, so esptool.py cannot use the common transistor circuit to drive EN/RESET and BOOT pins to go into bootloader in order to flash the board. You need to manually go put it into programming mode or implement the handshake pins.

Other than it likey not being a working or trouble-free, you need to consider the programming aspects, and you likely forgot that RS-485 is not a two-wire interface, the devices must share a ground reference as well. Implementing half-duplex requires both ends to understand the half-duplexness so in the end it may be easier to do a transparent full-duplex link. Or use Ethernet with conversion box to serial.


